# PHP - EMail sending does not work (no email is received)

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, sendmail.exe

With the following code I should send some E-Mails for my mobileapp away. But it does not work.

It Shows Enquiry sent! but there is no email received.... What is going wrong here?

```
 <?php
 //setup variables from input    
 $EMAIL = "marco.seiz@bluewin.ch";    

 //setup message    
 $message = "Enquiry from: ";

 $message = wordwrap($message, 70);   


 //email enquiry details to site owner    
 if (mail($EMAIL, "test", $message))    
 {    
  echo "Enquiry sent!";    
 } else    
 {
  echo "fail!";    
 }
?>
```

php.ini Settings:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 487

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mseiz93@gmail.com

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program files\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "C:\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the \xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got anything set up in your `php.ini` file that sets the SMTP server - and is it one that will accept your connection?

Comment: I set up the php.ini with following Options: [mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 487

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mseiz93@gmail.com

Comment: And BAM! There it is, Gmail will require SMTP authentication, which is something that is not possible via the normal `mail()` function in PHP. Look into PHPMailer, it will let you authenticate (Tell the server who you are) and with that, it will be happy to send on your behalf.

Comment: I'll try that danks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should be using PHPMailer or similar, so that the emails are being sent correctly through an SMTP server with authentication, but adding these headers should help a bit.

Having said that, Gmail's SMTP server will definitely require authentication, so despite your XAMPP config, the mail <strike>probably</strike> won't get through.

```
<?php
 //setup variables from input    
 $EMAIL = "marco.seiz@bluewin.ch";    

 //setup message    
 $message = "Enquiry from: ";

 $message = wordwrap($message, 70);   

 $headers = "From: mseiz93@gmail.com\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain\n";

 //email enquiry details to site owner    
 if (mail($EMAIL, "test", $message, $headers))    
 {    
  echo "Enquiry sent!";    
 } else {
  echo "fail!";    
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to set headers, For debugging use http://mailcatcher.me/ small app that catches all the mails sent. There is a similar tool for windows too